# "As did I" vs "So did I"

Tags: word-choice, so-vs-as

Which is the (more) correct response?

> Me - "We have more tweaks for the ABC job"
>
> Other - "Really? I thought we'd completed that job!"
>
> Me - "As did I / So did I"

Thank you for any suggestions you can offer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both *As did I* and *So did I* are grammatically correct. *As did I* is very formal and may sound awkward in informal conversations. Another more informal way of saying it would be simply *Me too*.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatically correct. If you are in a conversation and say " As did I" it would be seen to be unusual in the text. If using in an essay for school it would be appropriate, probably even recognized for using it many don't write it like that.