# so angry / as angry as he is

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style

In English class today, I wrote the following sentence:

> *If Susan had told Tom the truth, he would not be so angry.*

It seems to me that "so angry" is not really the best way of saying it. Is "as angry as he is" better? Or do you have any other suggesting?

Comment: They mean very much the same thing, in context.

Comment: No difference, other than "tone", which is up to you to judge.  "As angry as he is" is a bit more "detached" in tone.

Comment: In fact when I was young half a century ago I was formally taught that *so* **must** be used rather than *as* with a negative. That "rule" appears to have vanished from the normativist corpus.

Comment: possible duplicate of [“so long as” vs. “as long as”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106555/so-long-as-vs-as-long-as). Also [“as far as” vs. “so far as” vs. “in so far as”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102168/) and [“As did I” vs “So did I”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63094/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are writing *"as angry as he is"* you are using a very **neutral** form of [comparison](http://www.eltbase.com/notes.php?id=549).

Whereas using "so angry", you are [noticing](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/so) how **extremely** angry Tom is.

In both case you are saying that the result of the lie is that Tom is angry. But you how you wrote it in class, you underlined that he was **very** angry.

Comment: For me, with german as my first language, it sounded a bit to german with the "so". So thank you for the clarification.